# Cannot install php 7.2 on Raspbian

Tags: php, debian, raspbian

I cannot install php 7.2 on Raspbian.
I used the last Raspbian (Release date : 2017-11-29) with a Debian Stretch 9.1 : https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

I followed the instructions from https://www.colinodell.com/blog/2016-12/installing-php-7-1 :

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt-get update
```

But when I try

```
apt-get install -y php7.2
```

A get the below errors :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install -y php7.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.2 but it is not installable or
               php7.2-fpm but it is not installable or
               php7.2-cgi but it is not installable
      Depends: php7.2-common but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Someone can help me ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this repository providing ARM binaries? I’m not sure, this might be why you can’t install it.

Comment: EDIT: apparently it does. Did you check `lsb_release -sc` returned “stretch”? Does `apt-get update` downloaded this repo too?

Comment: Yes, it return "Stretch".

Comment: Can you retry install `php7.1` at least? `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install php7.1`

Comment: The result is unfortunatly the same : 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.1 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.1 but it is not installable or
               php7.1-fpm but it is not installable or
               php7.1-cgi but it is not installable
      Depends: php7.1-common but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason, the package php7.1 and php7.2 isn't in the stretch repo :(.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70388/how-to-install-php-7-1

Have to wait an update ...

Comment: That’s exactly why you added the `https://packages.sury.org/php/` repo. As a result, apt should download php from the sury.org repository, not the (default) stretch one. I installed php7.1 on stretch several times (also it’s very likely php will stay at 7.0 during the whole stretch life).

Comment: For stretch there are only php7.1 and php7.1-xsl. Same for 7.2 within sury.org repo.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/579

It seems that Debian packages for newer PHP versions are not yet released for the ARM architecture.
I would like to contribute for building such packages, but there is no activity on the issue after my last post.

An option to install PHP7.1 or newer would be to compile and install it yourself. For some examples, you may want to check http://yoestuve.es/blog/compile-php-7-for-raspberry-pi-with-memcached/. I would also suggest to use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` in order to facilitate easier uninstallation later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not look like there will be a higher version than PHP 7.0 for raspberrys with stretch. Here you can see the PHP versions for current and future raspbian releases:
https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=php

You will have to upgrade to buster, then you will get PHP 7.3. Here is how:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/